# Trying to pad an image with symmetric using np.pad

Tags: numpy, conv-neural-network, padding

I'm trying to add 5 pixels worth of padding all around the image I have currently. The images are 150x150 pixels and I want to resize them into 160x160 with symmetric padding for my CNN.

Here is the code I am using:

```
for need_pad_img in os.listdir(old_images_path+'split_images'):   
    if need_pad_img.endswith(".jpg") and not need_pad_img.startswith("."):
        image = Image.open(old_images_path + 'split_images/' + need_pad_img)
        data = asarray(image)
        new_data = np.pad(data, pad_width=5, mode='symmetric')
        gen_img = Image.fromarray(new_data).astype(np.uint8).convert('RGB').save(old_images_path + 'split_images/' + "pad_" + need_pad_img)
```

However, I am getting error:

```
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/env_tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2751, in fromarray
    raise TypeError("Cannot handle this data type: %s, %s" % typekey) from e

TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 13), |u1
```

When I run `new_data.shape` I get `(160,160,13)` and when I run `new_data.dtype` I get `dtype('uint8')`.

Comment: Padding the 3d array (with channels) could be problem.  Whatis the `shape` and `dtype` for `data`?  If (n,m,3), typical for a color image, padding channels adds 5 and 5, to make 13.  That's not what you want.  You need to specify padding for all 3 dimensions, something like `((5,5),(5,5),(0,0))`.

Comment: ```data.shape``` is ```(150,150,3)``` and ```data.dtype``` is ```uint8```. Your suggestion worked for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to `np.pad`, consider allocating an image of the size you want and placing the original in it:

```
new_data = np.zeros((160, 160, *data.shape[2:]), dtype=np.uint8)
new_data[5:-4, 5:-4, ...] = data
```

For a more general solution, you could compute `5` and `-4` as `(new_data.shape[0] - data.shape[0]) // 2` and `(data.shape[0] - new_data.shape[0] - 1) // 2`, respectively.